# Success or failure method is not calling using retrofit in android

Tags: android

In MainActivity.java **//Root URL of our web service**
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://pratikbutani.x10.mx"; RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
                .build();

```
    //Creating an object of our api interface
    BooksAPI api = adapter.create(BooksAPI.class);

    //Defining the method
    api.getBooks(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Contact> list, Response response) {
            //Dismissing the loading progressbar

            //Storing the data in our list
            books = list;

            //Calling a method to show the list
            showList();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            //you can handle the errors here
        }
    });
```

public interface BooksAPI {

```
/*Retrofit get annotation with our URL
   And our method that will return us the list ob Book
*/
@GET("/json_data.json")
public void getBooks(Callback<List<Contact>> response);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//retrofit class

```
public class NetworkContext {

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://xyz/";

private Map<String, Object> services;

private Retrofit retrofit;

private static final NetworkContext INSTANCE = new NetworkContext();

private NetworkContext() {
    services = new HashMap<>();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
}

public static NetworkContext getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

public synchronized <T> T getService(Class<T> clazz) {
    String key = clazz.getName();
    if (services.containsKey(key)) {
        return (T) services.get(key);
    } else {
        T newClass = retrofit.create(clazz);
        services.put(key, newClass);
        return newClass;
    }
}    
}
```

//api interface

```
public interface APIInterface {

@GET("will be attached with the base url")
Call<Model> getData();
}
```

//calling

```
   Call call = apiInterface.getData();
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            Model model = (Model) response.body();
            // here you can retrieve data 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Comment: in your activity or fragment (or presenter if you are following MVP architecture)